# how to change row index back to a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, indexing, dataframe

i have a dataframe, after grouping, it is like this now:

[image]

now i want to move row index(name) to be the first column, how to do that ?
i tried to do like this:

```
gr.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but the effect is like this:

[image]

name field now has count information,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify the `drop` parameter, as as it means, it will drop the index, and also probably better to rename the index, since you have a `name` column already:

```
gr.index.name = "company"
gr = gr.reset_index()
```

Comment: thanks, is there a better way ? as there will be a field 'name' with count information, then i need to remove it and then rename 'company' to be 'name',

Comment: You can drop column with `drop()` function. So if the name column is to be dropped, you can do `gr.drop('name', axis=1).reset_index()` without renaming index.